# Can't change color default folders yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, finder, color

I've got a brand new mac with Yosemite 10.10.2
and I dislike the blue color of the folders

I'm looking for a proper way to change ALL folders's color

I've seen that http://yukiyamashina.github.io/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-change-the-color-of-default-folder-icons-in-OS-X-Yosemite/

But I can't find the folder CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/

Is this because I've got Yosemite 10.10.2 ?

Comment: I used LiteIcon: http://www.freemacsoft.net/liteicon/ to replace Yosemite default folder with Mavericks default folder. That's MUCH less garish.

Comment: I just checked it on a newly set up machine and the folder is there. Are you sure you're looking for that folder under `/System/Library` and not `/Library` or `~/Library`?

Comment: mmgross, thanks you're right, i was looking under /library and not /System/library

Comment: Litelcon unfortunally doesn't work under 10.10.2... But if you think the yukiyamashina is perillous, I shall wait

Comment: LiteIcon seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try candy Bar, I use it to change my icons and it works all the time. 
It's no longer supported by it's developers but the current version still works

http://www.panic.com/blog/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/

Comment: I've tried to download CandyBar but it's not supported by my Yosemite 10.10.2
"Unqualified system"

Comment: Yea it says unqualified on my system as well (10.10.2) but still works for me :)

Comment: I can't apply !